# how to pass values to layouts in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

In my default layout I have 3 links, i need to pass values to these links from search action colleges controller.

My default layout links

```
 <li class="single-link">
<a   href=<?php echo ROOTPATH.'Inventions';?>>Invention</a>    </li>
<li class="single-link"><!-- Using class="single-link" for links with no dropdown -->
<a   href=<?php echo ROOTPATH.'technology';?>>Technology</a>   </li>
<li class="single-link"><!-- Using class="single-link" for links with no dropdown -->
<a   href=<?php echo ROOTPATH.'enterper';?>>Enters</a>   </li>
<li class="single-link">
```

My search view form

```
<div class="searchbox" align="center">
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="/inno/colleges/search" >
   <label><span class="style14">Enter College Name</span>
     <span class="style14">
     <input type="text" id="tags" name="data[College][name]"  size="70"/>
     </span><span class="style12">     </span><span class="style10">     </span>     </label>
   <label>
   <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Explore"/>
   </label>
 </form>
</div>
```

In all 3 above href i need to add one more parameter which I set from seacrh action? can we do this ?

Comment: `from search action colleges controller.` - from in what sense?

Comment: @AD7six i have added my form as well

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the values in the same way as you pass the values in view.

`In Action`

`$this->set('yourkey', 'your-value');`

And in layout you can get `'your-value' in $yourkey variable`

Comment: I have given same, i did not get the value in layout, so i posted this on stack, any other solutions ?

Comment: which cakephp version you are using

Comment: I am using cakephp 2.3

Comment: Try doing it in the action instead of the view, if you haven't already?

Comment: Can you show your code you put `controller-action` and in `layout` to set and get the view variable.

Answer (score 0):

Correct way to get Values from Action to a View (Layouts too).
Is to set them in the Action like that :

In Seach-Action:

```
$this->set("testing","testing_string");
```

at the layout (default.ctp)

```
<?=$testing?>
```

You will may need them initialized otherwise if you enter the Application
you will get an undefined Variable Error.

Comment: So you want to set those values in your Search-Action and use them in the default.ctp. is that correct?

Comment: okay. You just have to set those Variables in the Search-Action and use them in your default.ctp like I write in my answer. Isnt that working?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting

```
$this->set("variable_name","contents");
```

in the AppController's `beforeFilter()` method (if you haven't got that, just create `public function beforeFilter() { ... }` )

Comment: Yes if we set it in appcontroller we will get the value in default layout but i dont need like that i just need from my college controller..

Comment: Ok. Can you post the code you're using to set the variable please? Just give the whole action in your controller if you can.